# How to check if Google location accuracy is set to improve or not?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on geofencing on Android. Before Android 9 high accuracy location mode was required in order for geofences to work. I could easily check that with SettingsApi. Now, in Android 9 there is something called Google location accuracy. In order for geofences to work that option must be set to improve. I simply can not find a way to check if this option is on or off. If this option is not enabled I get error 1000 from geofence client. It could be a workaround so that I try to add the geofence and if I get error I know it must be enabled. But there must be a way for me to check if its on or off.

This is how I check location mode:

```
public int getLocationMode(Context context){

return Settings.Secure.getInt(activityUnderTest.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

}
```

Comment: i don't think this is a bad question but consider posting some examples of how you would have done it previously, questions like these are a bit easier to understand with code attached